# How to update new column in a data frame based on matching IDs from another data frame in r

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello all I am trying to update my `df1` with matching ids from `df2`. Hence the `df1` datasets should not be increased or decreased inorder to  maintain the row count respectively. .my df1 looks like

```
ID   Record Date    Gender  DOB Registration_Date
123  08-05-2012       NA    NA   NA
123  06-05-2013       NA    NA   NA
234  08-08-2011       NA    NA   NA
234  09-06-2012       NA    NA   NA
335  09-09-2001       NA    NA   NA
335  08-09-2002       NA    NA   NA
335  10-10-2003       NA    NA   NA
425  28-11-2004       NA    NA   NA
425  27-08-2006       NA    NA   NA
```

My `df2` looks like

```
ID   Gender     DOB     Registration_Date
123    F    05-06-1990    28-08-2012
234    M    01-02-0991    05-06-2011
335    F    06-12-1996    07-08-2000
425    M    17-12-1999    09-07-2003
```

Expected Results :

```
ID  Record Date  Gender     DOB     Registration_Date
123 08-05-2012    F     05-06-1990   28-08-2012
123 06-05-2013    F     05-06-1990   28-08-2012
234 08-08-2011    M     01-02-0991   05-06-2011
234 09-06-2012    M     01-02-0991   05-06-2011
335 09-09-2001    F     06-12-1996   07-08-2000
335 08-09-2002    F     06-12-1996   07-08-2000
335 10-10-2003    F     06-12-1996   07-08-2000
425 28-11-2004    M     17-12-1999   09-07-2003
425 27-08-2006    M     17-12-1999   09-07-2003
```

Comment: Did you try `merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID')` ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thanks but other than merge any other possibilities because it results in duplicate rows that are unidentified. kindly suggest better way.

Comment: It doesn't result in duplicates for the example that you have shared. Can you update your post so that we can reproduce the issue that you are facing?